# Three questions about Evans proof of the converse to the mean value property

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

(Evans p26) Converse to mean value property.

**My three questions are in bold- and the proof in question is written verbatim at the end.**

If $u\in C^2(U)$ satisfies:
$$u(x)=-\!\!\!\!\!\!\int_{\partial B(x,r)} u dS$$
for each ball $B(x,r)\subset U$, then $u$ is harmonic.

He writes that if $u\not\equiv 0,$ there exists some ball $B(x,r)\subset U$ such that $\Delta u >0$. First I can't see why this is true. He is saying that everywhere on that ball, $\Delta u>0$ right? **Why is such a ball guaranteed to exist?**

- Next he says then that for $\phi(r)=\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(y)dS(y)$ that $0=\phi'(r)$, **but is that not only the case *because* $u$ was harmonic?**
- Lastly, **why is that a proof by contradiction**, surely he had just shown the contrapositive.

---

> Proof verbatim in case that's not clear:
>   If $u\not\equiv 0,$ there exists some ball $B(x,r)\subset U$ such that, say $\Delta u >0$ within $B(x,r)$. But then for $\phi$ as above, $$0=\phi'(r)=\frac{r}{n}-\!\!\!\!\!\!\int_{B(x,r)}\Delta u(y) dy>0,$$
>   a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He writes  "if $\Delta u \not\equiv0$, there exists some ball such that, say, $\Delta u > 0$". The "say" here is really a "without loss of generality". Since there must be a point $x$ where $\Delta u \ne 0$, then we can assume WLOG that $\Delta u(x) > 0$ - otherwise just replace $u$ with $-u$ or equivalently $>$ with $<$. By continuity of $\Delta u$ (remember that we assume $u \in C^2$) we in fact have $\Delta u>0$ in some ball around $x$.

The mean value property is the claim $u(x) = \phi(r)$ for all $r$; so if we assume this holds then $\phi'(r) = 0$ since it's the derivative of a constant.

You could pose this as a proof by contrapositive instead, yes: just get rid of the $0=$ before $\phi'(r)$ and instead conclude that $\phi'(r) > 0$ implies $\phi(r) \ne u(x)$ for some $r$, so the mean value property does not hold.